# CreatedAtRoute with OK(200) code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Whether it's acceptable RESTful design or not, I'd like to give a result as like below code doing but with `200 OK` StatusCode.

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = model.Id }, model);
```

Above one provides `Location` header which utilize given `id` route variable and json serialized `model` content.

```
return Ok(); // how to make it with this?
```

Note that I'm using ASP.NET WebApi2 (.Net 4.6) template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this, create a custom `IHttpActionResult` that decorates `CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult` and updates the status code:

```
public class OkWithLocation<T> : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<T> _result;

    public OkWithLocation(CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<T> result)
    {
        _result = result;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await _result.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return response;
    }
}
```

And then use this in your controller action:

```
return new OkWithLocation<Model>(CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = model.Id }, model));
```

Maybe not the prettiest, but it gets the job done.